# What is this scrolling technique called?

Tags: html, scroll, slider, html5-video

Under the iPod Touch, when I click on the blue button the image will be scrolled to the right/left according to the image.

What is this technique called and is it achievable using pure HTML5?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: @Jonathan: tagging this [tag:ipod-touch] is not useful - this is not about the ipod, there is just an example on the ipod-touch website.

Comment: agree. I think someone added ipod touch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just another style of carosel/image gallery design. This is usually done with jQuery. And honestly you can find pre-built templates almost all around the web for this stuff. I have added a couple links below. If you have time check them out and post back with questions.

- [Coin Slider](http://workshop.rs/projects/coin-slider/)
- [Nivo Slider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/)
- [Presentation Cycle](http://www.gayadesign.com/scripts/presentationCycle/)
- [BXSlider](http://bxslider.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about only HTML 5, but through CSS3's target pseudo class ( http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#target-pseudo )  you can allow users to scroll through images.

The problem with this is, of course, that without JavaScript the functionality is lost in older browsers, and having it animate through the various images automatically (without a user selecting an image to drive the :target class) is going to be difficult at best.

Paul Hayes' CSS3 modal window ( http://www.paulrhayes.com/2011-03/css-modal/ ) explains a lot of these issues, and gives you a lot of the theory behind how one might implement a slider through CSS3.

In the end though, unless you're trying to do a proof of concept, or something that shows the world how cool CSS3 can be, you're better off with one of the JavaScript solutions that Jake has linked — they'll work in the real world.